# Warning: pattern.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, gruntjs

I'm trying to use AWS plugin on Grunt to upload statics to S3, but I'm having problems on files key. I have this error on my console. Any idea? Thanks!`Warning: pattern.indexOf is not a function`

```
aws_s3: {
  options: {
    accessKeyId: 'ID',
    secretAccessKey: 'Key',
    bucket: 'globalx',
    region: 'us-east-1',
    progress: 'progressBar',
  },
  files: [
    {'action': 'upload', expand: true, cwd: 'css', src: ['style.css'], dest: 'app/styles/'}
  ]
},
```

Comment: I see a data structure, but I don't see the code that is producing that error.

Comment: do you have some error stack trace?

Comment: @sweaver2112 this is an internal error of grunt that is shown very often but caused by different things. The presented structure is most likely what causes the error...